# Get name of test-file inside of flutter test

Tags: flutter

Assume I have a flutter test file `foo_test.dart` with:

```
void main() {
 final file = ...how to get the path of this file... 'foo_test.dart';
 ...
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet allows to retrieve the file containing `main()`:

```
final mainFile = Uri.parse(RegExp(r'#.*main \((.*):.*:.*\)')
        .firstMatch(StackTrace.current.toString())
        .group(1))
    .toFilePath();
```